# Correct validating uniqueness of uploaded images which allows posting without uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I want to allow posting either messages without images or with a unique image, I added following code in my model

```
validates :image_fingerprint, :uniqueness => true
```

It forbids posting similar images but it forbids as well posting more than one message without image. I tried to add

> :allow_blank => true

and

> :allow_nil => true

but it leads to the following error:

> TypeError in PostsController#create
>   can't convert nil into String

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is `image_fingerprint` saved as `nil` or an empty string when no image is present?

Comment: image_fingerprint it's md5 hash generated by paperclip, it's saved into "image_fingerprint" database column of type string, when there is no image the the cell is blank, it's all what I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:unless` on validation, only if this attribute not blank

```
validates :image_fingerprint, :uniqueness => true, 
  :unless => Proc.new { |a| a.image_fingerprint.blank? }
```

Reference:

> You can associate the :if and :unless options with a symbol corresponding to the name of a method that will get called right before validation happens. This is the most commonly used option.
>
> Finally, it’s possible to associate :if and :unless with a Proc object which will be called. Using a Proc object gives you the ability to write an inline condition instead of a separate method. This option is best suited for one-liners.
>
> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation

Comment: I already tried something like that, it doesn't help, I still get "can't convert nil into String"

Comment: @user1887348, I think this error is not about validation but how you save the object. You may want to check if the value of image_fingerprint is nil if not filled. This is not acceptable, you need to convert this field into a blank string if not filled.

Comment: Oh, I just thought the same :3 but it was not the case. I found the mistake, the reason was another function, called before create, which I completely forgot of, that function depended on the file name and failed when it was nil. It was so stupid on my part not to read error messages completely. Everything works now when I added :allow_blank =>true to the correctness check and :unless => Proc.new { |a| a.image_fingerprint.blank? } to the function call.